# I don't understand my mystake trying to initialise and fill a dynamic 2D array using data in a file

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, scanf

first post here. I am trying, through a function to initialise a 2D array. Before I use the function, I don't know the array dimensions so I think I have to use malloc. Moreoever the data I try to read is positionned in a .txt file so I use the fscanf function. Here is the code which is surely more understandable.

```
    typedef struct Level Level;   
    struct Level{
        int height;
        int width;
        int **matrix;
     };

     int main(){
     Level test;
     Level *testPtr=&test;
     getLvl(testPtr);
     int i,j;
     printf("height=%d,width=%d",test.height,test.width); //veryfing I get the right height and width
     for(i=0;i<test.height;i++){
         for(j=0;j<test.width;j++){
             printf("test[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,test.matrix[i][j]);//printing the value supposed to be there
          }
      }

     }
     void getLvl(Level *testPtr){
         FILE *doc=NULL;
         doc=fopen("doc.txt","r");  //open my file
         fscanf(doc,"%d",&testPtr->height);    //get the height and width
         fscanf(doc,"%d",&testPtr->width);
         test->matrix=malloc(sizeof(int*)*testPtr->height*testPtr->width);  //initialise the matrix as an array of pointer
         int i,j;
         for(i=0;i<testPtr->height;i++){
             test->matrix[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*testPtr->width);   //allocate every elements of the array enough memory to store the data of every 
             for(j=0;j<test->width;j++){
                 fscanf(doc,"%d",matrix[i][j]);
              }
         }

     }
```

So when I try to execute my code I have no issue getting the height and width. However getting the values of the array make the console crashes. From what I know this comes from an issue trying to reach memory I don't have access to. 
My doc file looks something like this :

```
10
10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

EDIT :
Here is the original code (in French) :

```
typedef struct Niveau Niveau;
struct Niveau{
 int hauteur;
 int largeur;
 int **cases;
 int positionX;
 int positionY;

};
void getLvl(Niveau *test);


int main()
{
    Niveau test;
    Niveau *testPTR=&test;
    getLvl(testPTR);
    printf("hauteur vaut %d\n",test.hauteur);
    printf("largeur vaut %d\n",test.largeur);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            printf("Valeur de tableau[%d][%d] vaut %d\n",i,j,test.cases[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


void getLvl(Niveau *test){
    char verif;
    FILE* doc=NULL;
    doc=fopen("doc.txt","r");
    fscanf(doc,"%c",&verif);
    int i,j;
    if(verif=='A'){
        fscanf(doc,"%d",&test->hauteur);
        fscanf(doc,"%d",&test->largeur);
    }
    fscanf(doc,"%c",&verif);
    if(verif=='B'){
        test->cases=malloc(sizeof(int*)*test->hauteur*test->largeur);
        for (i=0;i<test->hauteur;i++){
            test->cases[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*test->largeur);
            for(j=0;j<test->largeur;j++){
                fscanf(doc,"%d",test->cases[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main the txt file is exactly :

```
A
10
10
B
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
C
```

Comment: Are you saying that you can compile the shown code without any warning? Please double check that it is a [mre]. I doubt the shown order of things.

Comment: Does your code compile?  `fscanf(doc,"%d",&matrix[i][j];` is missing a parenthesis. In function getLvl(..)

Comment: My bad guys I rewrote the text (badly) because I had to translate in English I changed a few things if you want to look again. Thanks anynway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here add one space `fscanf(doc, " %c", &verif);` in this `fscanf` before `%c`,otherwise you will take `\n` as input.

and here `fscanf(doc, "%d", test->cases[i][j]);` add `&` to your `fscanf` like this `fscanf(doc, "%d", &test->cases[i][j]);`

Comment: So I have corrected my mistakes regarding the ) and *. Sorry if my code is not perfect I rewrite it for you in order to translate text and explanation as it was firstly coded in french. For the &matrix part should i just remove the & and this part would assocaite the fscanf value to matrix[i][j] ?

Comment: Damn I am really making dumb mistakes because of rewriting my code. So I clearly see my mystake considering the test variable (the issue was not here in the original code). And I was also not using the & in my code yet it still crash. Btw when I try to printf the value I get pointers.

Comment: Here you go, i made the change

Comment: @FirminExertier hope this help.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @FirminExertier I meant my updated answer. I changed it completely.

Comment: aha my bad didn't see.  So glad your fix worked ! I forgot about the space thing which cause me issues in the past. Thanks a lot for your help